# Can I have a Teamcity build triggering an Azure Devops build job?

Tags: azure-devops, teamcity

I'm migrating Teamcity to Azure Devops, as with our on-prem infrastructure. During that period we'll have  both Teamcity and Azure Devops deployment for different infrastructures, but we want to reduce the amount of human intervention. So I was thinking in having either Teamcity triggering the Azure Devops build, or vice Versa. I think it would be easier to implement a powershell script that triggers the build on Azure Devops, instead the other way around because of compatibility issues, or version issues(old version).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use Azure Devops api to trigger the build. You would use this api call with appropriate body:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.0
```

Reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

I'm not familiar with Azure Devops powershell modules if any, but they might work as well.